# Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 33748) Without no reasone

Tags: python, django

I'am using that command line

> [ python manager.py runserver ]

and run successfully but all i get

> Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 33716)

without errors that is slow my project .

manager.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "lambo.settings")

from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

how can i solve that problem  ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Are you surrounding your command in brackets? Also, what does `manager.py` look like? We need to see your code in order to help you debug

Comment: Updated   now you can see my manager.py